# Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::limit() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

I am calling the function below and I always get back:

```
Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::limit()
```

I don't know the reason, I have the same error also with

```
Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::get()
```

Do I have to translate the limit function in somenthing like this to avoid the problem?

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10



function get_current_page_records_users($limit, $start)
{

$this->db->limit($limit, $start);   //here
$query = $this->db->get("dbo.tbl_Login");


if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a select first.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```

Also, `$this->db->get()` is not used in conjunction with other methods. `->get()` is intended to be used on it's own and calling it will probably end up ignoring any other method calls such as `->select()` or `->limit()`. See the [In the CodeIgniter Query Builder Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) for more info.

You could also define limit and offset using `->get()` like so.

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);
```

Finally, I think `ODBC` is disabled in CodeIgniter. See [this Github issue "Re-enable Query Builder for ODBC driver"](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/5197).

Comment: Now I have Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::select()

Comment: if use $this->db->count_all("dbo.tbl_Login"); no problem but with other methods I have errors

Comment: @StefanoMaglione Hmm, what version of CodeIgniter are you using? obdc may be disabled in your version. https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/5197

Comment: @StefanoMaglione I've added an edit that might explain that issue.

Comment: I am using codeigniter 3.1.6, but strange that count_all works!

Comment: I have re-enabled odbc, now i get Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecDirect

Comment: "Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecDirect" is the error message? Does the query return a dataset or false?

Comment: Error Number: 01000

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor.

SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Login LIMIT 1, 1

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/medica-CodeIgniter-3.1.6/system/database/DB_driver.php

Comment: @StefanoMaglione It seems that it could be a lot of things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712170/executing-sql-directly-no-cursor-error-in-access-2007-vb-code for more information on debugging and finding the real (more helpful) error message. I don't know enough about this type of database to help you further, but if this answer was helpful, please do accept.